# Editing column headers in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to edit numerical column headers - based on a given criteria, to text.
I'm trying to go from 01 ! to Gold, 02 ! to Silver and so on.

I am using `python 3.7` out of PyCharm 2018.2.2 Community Edition.

I keep getting the following error message:

> "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable"

when I run the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name, index_col=0, index =0, 
                   skiprows=1)
for col in df.columns:
   if col[:2]=='01':
        df.rename(columns={col:'Gold'+col[4:]}, inplace=True)
   if col[:2]=='02':
        df.rename(columns={col:'Silver'+col[4:]}, inplace=True)
   if col[:2]=='03':
        df.rename(columns={col:'Bronze'+col[4:]}, inplace=True)
   if col[:1]=='№':
        df.rename(columns={col:'#'+col[1:]}, inplace=True)
```

However, the same code runs fine out of a JuPyter notebook.

Comment: Just fixing you code before you for loop adding 

`df.columns=df.columns.astype(str)`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!